# VK Social Network: How to get album id's from VK social network in ios

Tags: ios, social-networking, vk

I'am using this following api(https://vk.com/pages?oid=-17680044&p=API_Method_Description) to get photo's from the album for vk social network,but i didn't get the user profile albumid & also the wallpaper albumid anybody can help me....? Thank yu for advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Jus got the answer from vk api,
 `NSString *getWallUploadServer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getAll?owner_id=%@&access_token=%@",user_id,accessToken];` 
You can get the user_id & accessToken from the vk login. I pass all the needed parameters i got the  response from server.. Thank yu